# asp.net mvc3 webgrid shows error

Tags: ienumerable

The below code throws error in IEnumerable conversion issues. Please guide me if I am mising some conversion from controller to view.

controller Code

```
  public ActionResult Index()
        {
            DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            var kk = (from x in db.tblTests select x).ToList();
            return View(kk);
        }
```

View Code

```
@model MvcApplication4.Models.sampleDoamin

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@{

  var grid = new WebGrid(Model, defaultSort:"name");

}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

Model Code

```
public class sampleDoamin
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: _What error do you get?_  Did you read the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the view as taking a `sampleDomain`, but you passed it an `List<T>` of some unknown type.
That won't work.

Comment: I tried adding @model IEnumberable<MvcApplication4.Models.sampleDoamin> to view but it didnt work. Please guide me on this.